# Regular expression for email accepting consecutive dots

Tags: javascript, regex, email

Here is my Regex

```
((^[a-zA-Z0-9]?[^<>()\[\]\\,:\s@"]*(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9])|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))
```

The above regex accepting two consecutive dots in local part of the email for example
**test.one@gmail.com** is valid email is working fine but **test..one@gmail.com** where as here it taking it as valid email which not a valid one. Please help in teaking the above Regex thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow only one dot in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952093/how-to-allow-only-one-dot-in-regex)

Answer (score 2):

This regex validates an email address, and makes sure no consecutive dots are used:

```js
var email1 = 'test.one@gmail.com';
var email2 = 'test..one@gmail.com';
var re = /^[\w%\+\-]+(\.[\w%\+\-]+)*@[\w%\+\-]+(\.[\w%\+\-]+)+$/;
var val1 = re.test(email1);
var val2 = re.test(email2);
console.log(email1 + ' ==> ' + val1);
console.log(email2 + ' ==> ' + val2);
```

Console output:

```
test.one@gmail.com ==> true
test..one@gmail.com ==> false
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `^...$` -- anchor at the beginning and end
- `[\w%\+\-]+` -- one or more word characters and other valid characters except dot
- `(...)*` -- make what's inside optional (zero or more occurrences)
- `(\.[\w%\+\-]+)*` -- zero or more occurrences of a dot, followed by valid characters
- `@` -- an `@` sign
- `[\w%\+\-]+(\.[\w%\+\-]+)+` -- followed by the same sequence, except that at least one occurrence is required

Please note that a proper validation based on the actual RFC-822 is very complex. Here is a regex with 6000+ chars that does that: [http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Balaji: Does that answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

This RegEx should test for almost all test cases including consecutive dots and special characters:

```js
const validEmail = 'something@something.com';
const invalidEmail = 'someth..ing@something.com';
var reg = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/i;

console.log(validEmail+' : ' + reg.test(validEmail));
console.log(invalidEmail+' : ' + reg.test(invalidEmail));
```

**Note:**
Although this regex will validate most of the test cases, emails are very tricky and you still should follow RFC-822 rules if you want to have an ultimate validator.
Check this link for more information: http://jkorpela.fi/rfc/822addr.html